# Randomly sampling an irregular raster extent in R

Tags: r, random, shapefile, sample, r-raster

Is there a function in the R raster package that is analogous to sampleRandom but which extracts n random pixel values from within an irregularly shaped polygon feature rather than a rectangular extent object?

I know there are alternative approaches such as generating random points within a polygon and then use the extract() function to get pixel values, but am wondering if there is a more direct path I have missed.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, there is not a single function for this.